# Shorter way of prompting for a height of x feet y inches?

Tags: java, validation

I'm currently working on a BMI calculator and just wondered if there was a shorter or more condensed version of doing the `if` validating statement.

I have currently done it this way for both Height and Weight, but I find it to be a mess and it seems to cluttered. There must be a way of shortening this down or condensing it.

```
boolean Hresult = false;
int resulth = 0;
while(Hresult == false) {

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your feet: ");
    int heightft = scanner.nextInt();

    if (heightft >=2 && heightft <=7 ){
        System.out.println("You entered: " + heightft);
        Hresult = true;
    }
    else {
           System.out.println("Please try again");  
           Hresult = false;
    }
    System.out.print("Please enter your inches: ");
    int heightin = scanner.nextInt();

    if (heightin >=0 && heightin <=11 ){
        System.out.println("You entered: " + heightin);
        Hresult = true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please try again");  
        Hresult = false;
    } 
    int resultin = (heightft * 12);
    resulth = (resultin + heightin);
}
return resulth;
```

Comment: That's not a natural way of asking for height. Users should be able to enter height as 5'9", for example, and the computer should parse it. It would also simplify the code.

Comment: I know, unfortunately I'm unsure of how to tell the console to read in the two different integers and then validate them.

Comment: Don't read two different integers. Read a single string and the extract the value(s) using a regular expression (keeping in mind that `6'` is shorthand for `6'0"` and you probably don't want to allow negative values).

Comment: Feature request: Add support for the metric system! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes, there are ways to improve it!

**Coding conventions**

First of all, you are not following some Java coding conventions of indentation and where to put `}`-characters and similar.

**Error messages**

"Please try again" is not a message that really describes what went wrong. If I would see that message my first reaction would be to try to enter **the exact same value** again, which would just give me the same error message.

**What your code does**

Your code is essentially divided into two parts. The first part is:

```
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your feet: ");
    int heightft = scanner.nextInt();

    if (heightft >= 2 && heightft <= 7) {
        System.out.println("You entered: " + heightft);
        Hresult = true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please try again");  
        Hresult = false;
    }
```

Second part:

```
    System.out.print("Please enter your inches: ");
    int heightin = scanner.nextInt();

    if (heightin >= 0 && heightin <= 11) {
        System.out.println("You entered: " + heightin);
        Hresult = true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please try again");  
        Hresult = false;
    }
```

Hresult in the first part of the code essentially **has no effect because it will be overwritten** by Hresult in the second part.

Now let's see what the common areas of this code are:

- Show a message
- Read an int from the Scanner
- Check the range of the entered value
- Show what you entered
- Return whether or not the result was successful.

This could become **it's own method**.

```
public static int inputWithExpectedRange(String message, int min, int max) {
    do {
        System.out.print(message);
        int value = scanner.nextInt();

        if (value >= min && value <= max) {
            System.out.println("You entered: " + value);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Expected a value between " + min + " and " + max + ". Please try again");  
        } 
    }
    while (value < min || value > max);
    return value;
}
```

Now what you can do is to call this method twice from your previously existing method. It is also likely that you will find use for that method when the user should enter his/her weight.

```
System.out.println(); // this will print a line break *before* entering the input-method.
int feet = inputWithExpectedRange("Please enter your feet: ", 2, 7);
int inches = inputWithExpectedRange("Please enter your inches: ", 0, 11));
return feet * 12 + inches;
```

Violà.

**An entirely different approach**

As mentioned in the comments to your question, you can also use [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info) to verify input and parse it. Here is a brief example of how to use Regular Expressions to input this. I will let you work on the details for it (such as making sure `feet` and `inches` are in the proper ranges). And you probably also want it inside some kind of loop (either `while` or `do-while`) to make sure that the user enters acceptable values.

```
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    String regex = "(\\d+)'(\\d+)\"";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Input was not in normal feet and inch format");
    }
    int feet = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int inches = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
```

If you enter `5'11"` the variable `feet` will be 5 and `inches` will be 11.

Comment: For better usability, I would use a very liberal regex, like `"(\\d+)(?:\s+|\s*[Ff']\\D*)(\\d+)"` (accepting any two numbers separated by whitespace or an apostrophe or anything starting with an "f"). Then `"5 ft. 5 in."` would also be acceptable. Since the regex is so sloppy, though I would echo the result as feedback.

Comment: I'd recommend handling the case of "6'" meaning 6'0", but otherwise I approve.

Answer (score 4):

@Simon has posted a good solution.  Also, several users have suggested that asking for feet and inches at the same time and parsing the response would yield a better user experience.  Since you asked for a code review, though, I'd just like to point out some concerns that are not directly related to the prompting problem.

#### Loop logic

Your while-loop doesn't make sense.  It looks like your intention is to retry the prompt on invalid input.  However, it doesn't actually do that.  Once it gets to the bottom of the loop, it's going to `return` a value immediately no matter what.

#### Variable usage

On top of that, I would add that you aren't using variables very effectively.

- **Naming two variables similarly** (`Hresult` and `resulth`) is confusing.
- A variable name starting with uppercase also defies **convention**.
- Attempting to indirectly influence the **execution flow using a variable** like `Hresult` is poor practice; you should eliminate such variables in favour of more active means such as `continue` and `break`.
- `resulth` is **superfluous**.  You can just `return 12 * heightft + heightin`.
- Even if you did need `resulth`, you should **declare it near the point of use** to reduce mental workload.

Answer (score 2):

Some people may find it more convinient to enter the height as something like `70"` to indicate 5 feet 10 inches. Why disallow that by requiring inches be 11 or fewer?

What about <s>exceptionally</s> abnormally short or <s>exceptionally</s> abnormally tall people?

Also, the code

```
if (heightin >=0 && heightin <=11 ){
```

would be much better off written as

```
if (heightin >=0 && heightin < 12 ){
```

since fractional inches do actually exist (even if your implementation doesn't support them).

Validation is not needed here, because, even if a user enters their info wrong, the only thing that can happen is that it might tell them the wrong BMI. Not a critical failure-means-people-die, or even failure-means-monetary-loss; It is only failure-means-try-again-for-free.

By restricting your program, you restrict its possible utility. What if someone wants to enter bogus info for fun? If you allow it, they will be happy, and if you filter it, they will not be.

Get rid of the validation entirely. Users should be able to enter whatever they want into your program, even unlikely values, and more code always means more bugs.

Answer (score -3):

What about some while blocks?

```
int heightft = 0;
boolean validHeight = false;
do {
    height = scanner.nextInt();
    validHeight = heightft >=2 && heightft <=7;
} while( !validHeight );
```

Comment: @Malachi I don't really agree that `while` is better coding practice / more readable than `do while`. They both have their uses I think. You have a (more or less) reliable source for that? As far as I can see, using `height` instead of `heightft` within the do-while loop is probably just a typo. Although I agree that this code could be improved, there's no use for a `validHeight` variable here. Just change the while condition.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, I agree with you. but the way that it is written it will fall into an infinite loop regardless of how the `while` statement is written, if the `heightft` is not valid.  it would be better as an `if` statement, which is what the OP already has.

Comment: @Malachi `do { heightft = scanner.nextInt(); } while (heightft < 2 || heightft > 7);` How would that be an infinite loop?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, my bad. I see it now.  still, if the code should be a `do while` then it should be written `do{height =scanner.nextInt();boolean validHeight = heightft >=2 && heightft<=7;}while(!validHeight);` if that is even possible otherwise it should be written as `while (!validHeight)...` it will still enter the while statement on the first run, and it is clear what the condition is